# Cant export/import functions js

Tags: javascript, node.js, syntax-error

Im using node.js and am trying to import functions from another script.

`The requested module './Module.js' does not provide an export named 'default'`
Is the error i recieved when trying to use

```js
module.exports = randomfunction;
```

For context, i used

```js
import randomfunction from "./module.js";
```

Comment: Try `import { randomfunction } from "./module.js";` or `import * as randomfunction from "./module.js";`

Comment: or you can try `export default randomfunction`

Comment: you have to use `const randomfunction = require('./randomfunction')` if you  use `module.exports = randomfunction`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is because Node.js thinks `Module.js` is a ES module but you have written it as a CommonJS module.

You have to tell Node.js if your module is CommonJS (uses `module.exports` and `require`) or ES (uses `import` and `export`).

You set the module type using a file extension:

- `.cjs` for CommonJS
- `.mjs` for ES modules
- `.js` for the package default

The package default is determined by the `type` property. If you specify `"type": "module"` then `.js` files will be treated as ES modules. If you don't specify that then it will treat them as CommonJS modules.

---

You appear to have set `"type": "module"` so you can use `import` in your `.js` files.

This means you have to rename your CommonJS module:

```
import randomfunction from "./module.cjs";
```

**or**

Rewrite your CommonJS module to be an ES module:

```
export default randomfunction;
```

Comment: What if I wanted to export from one script to another, and the opposite way as well? would I name both .cjs?

Comment: @lendo — Only if they are both CommonJS modules.